# Property 'sqlSessionFactory' or 'sqlSessionTemplate' are required in spring mock mvc test for spring boot with mybatis

Tags: spring-boot, testing, mybatis, spring-mvc-test

**the demo project location**

1. https://github.com/soliders/mockmvctest-ofspringboot-withmybatismapper
   https://github.com/soliders/mockmvctest-ofspringboot-withmybatismapper.git

explain:
the demo use Spring Boot/ mybatis-spring-boot-starter1.3.2/mybatis-spring-boot-starter-test and other basic components

problems:
1、when i'm use spring mock mvc to testing the controller of spring boot, it appear exception like this:Property 'sqlSessionFactory' or 'sqlSessionTemplate' are required
2、now i couldn't test for the controller,but i could process unit test for mybatis mapper

problem explain:

1. the demo can running well
2. use mybatis-spring-boot-start-test can process the unit test for
   mybatis mappers very normal.
3. when i test for controllers, if i use @AutoConfigureMybatis
   annotation, the test can pass,but it can not get the right datas
   from DB. the mapper's   query result is null. i think
   @AutoConfigureMybatis simulate the real mapper's operation
4. now exit on series problem, it is if the service using mapper's
   result to process something,i couldn't testing the service rightly.

> so,if some one can help me to solve the problem? i had already search google for more than two days,but found no solution

some codes blow:

> controller code

```
package com.wqk.mockmvctestofspringbootwithmybatismapper.controller;

import com.wqk.mockmvctestofspringbootwithmybatismapper.dto.CdnNation;
import com.wqk.mockmvctestofspringbootwithmybatismapper.service.TestService;
import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiImplicitParam;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiImplicitParams;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponses;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@Api(value = "AbilityOpenController", description = "xxxAPI")
public class TestController {


  private final TestService testService;

  public TestController(TestService testService) {
    this.testService = testService;
  }
  @GetMapping("/test/spring/mock/mvc/test/with/mybatis/mapper/v{version}")
  @ApiOperation(value = "xx[已经实现]", notes = "xxx", httpMethod = "GET")
  @ApiImplicitParams({
      @ApiImplicitParam(name = "version", value = "版本号，例：1", required = true, paramType = "path", dataType = "String"),
      @ApiImplicitParam(name = "year", value = "年，例：2018", required = true, paramType = "query", dataType = "String"),
      @ApiImplicitParam(name = "month", value = "月，例：1", required = true, paramType = "query", dataType = "String"),
  })
  @ApiResponses({
      //@ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "内部服务异常，请联系管理员")
  })
     public List<CdnNation> getCdnNationParams(
      @PathVariable(value = "version") String version, 
 @RequestParam("year") String year,
      @RequestParam("month") String month) {
        switch (version) {
          case "1":
            return testService.getCdnNationParams(year, month);
          default:
            return testService.getCdnNationParams(year, month);
       }
  }
}
```

> controller test code

```
    package com.wqk.mockmvctestofspringbootwithmybatismapper.controller;
    import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
    import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
    import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
    import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

    import com.wqk.mockmvctestofspringbootwithmybatismapper.dto.CdnNation;
    import com.wqk.mockmvctestofspringbootwithmybatismapper.mapper.TestMapper;
    import com.wqk.mockmvctestofspringbootwithmybatismapper.service.TestService;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import org.mybatis.spring.boot.test.autoconfigure.AutoConfigureMybatis;
    import org.mybatis.spring.boot.test.autoconfigure.MybatisTest;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.AutoConfigureTestDatabase;
    import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
    import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
    import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
    import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletResponse;


    import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
    import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    //@MybatisTest
    //@AutoConfigureMybatis
    @WebMvcTest(TestController.class)
    public class TestControllerTest {

      @Autowired
      private MockMvc mockMvc;

      @MockBean
      private TestService testService;
      //通过MockBean来mock Mapper,这样可以通过测试，但是失去了真实的Mapper文件读取数据库的能力。无法对service层的实现逻辑进行单元测试。
     //@MockBean
     //private TestMapper testMapper;
     //使用@AutoConfigureMybatis也可以通过测试，但是无法获取真正的Mapper操作获取的数据。
     //@AutoConfigureMybatis


      @Test
      public void getCdnNationParams() throws Exception {
      List<CdnNation> serviceResults = new ArrayList<>();
    /*serviceResults.add(
        CdnNation.builder().year("2018").month("2").bandWidthMean("24.33").bandWidthPeak("33.33")
            .totalDomainNums("44").totalServeProvinces("76").build());*/
    when(testService.getCdnNationParams("2018", "2")).thenReturn(serviceResults);

    MockHttpServletResponse response = this.mockMvc
        .perform(get("/test/spring/mock/mvc/test/with/mybatis/mapper/v1?year=2018&month=2").accept(MediaType.ALL))
        .andDo(print())
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andReturn()
        .getResponse();
    System.out.println("=====mock test result======");
    System.out.println(response.getContentAsString());
  }
}
```

> Mapper

```
 package com.wqk.mockmvctestofspringbootwithmybatismapper.mapper;

import com.wqk.mockmvctestofspringbootwithmybatismapper.dto.CdnNation;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Param;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Result;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Results;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.SelectProvider;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.JdbcType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface TestMapper {

  /**
   * @see TestMapperProvider#selectCdnNationAllIndicators(Map)
   * @param year
   * @param month
   * @return
   */
  @Results(value = {
      @Result(property = "year", column = "year", javaType = String.class, jdbcType = JdbcType.INTEGER),
      @Result(property = "month", column = "month", javaType = String.class, jdbcType = JdbcType.INTEGER),
      @Result(property = "bandWidthPeak", column = "bandwidth_peak", javaType = String.class, jdbcType = JdbcType.DOUBLE),
      @Result(property = "bandWidthMean", column = "bandwidth_mean", javaType = String.class, jdbcType = JdbcType.DOUBLE),
      @Result(property = "totalServeProvinces", column = "total_serve_provinces", javaType = String.class, jdbcType = JdbcType.DOUBLE),
      @Result(property = "totalDomainNums", column = "total_domain_nums", javaType = String.class, jdbcType = JdbcType.DOUBLE),
  })
  @SelectProvider(type = TestMapperProvider.class, method = "selectCdnNationAllIndicators")
  List<CdnNation> selectCdnNationAllIndicators(@Param("year") String year,
      @Param("month") String month);
}
```

> Mapper Provider

```
   package com.wqk.mockmvctestofspringbootwithmybatismapper.mapper;

import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.ibatis.jdbc.SQL;

public class TestMapperProvider {


  private final static String TABLE_NAME = "komect_data_product_abilityopen_cdnnation";

  public String selectCdnNationAllIndicators(Map<String, Object> parameters) {
    return new SQL() {
      {
        SELECT(
            "year,month,bandwidth_peak,bandwidth_mean,total_serve_provinces,total_domain_nums");
        FROM(TABLE_NAME);
        WHERE("(month <= #{month} and year = #{year}) or (year < #{year})");
        ORDER_BY("year desc ,month desc");
      }
    }.toString();
  }
}
```

> ServiceImpl

```
package com.wqk.mockmvctestofspringbootwithmybatismapper.service;

import com.wqk.mockmvctestofspringbootwithmybatismapper.dto.CdnNation;
import com.wqk.mockmvctestofspringbootwithmybatismapper.mapper.TestMapper;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService{

  private final TestMapper testMapper;

  public TestServiceImpl(TestMapper testMapper){
    this.testMapper = testMapper;
  }

  @Override
  public List<CdnNation> getCdnNationParams(String year, String month) {
    List<CdnNation> queryResult = testMapper.selectCdnNationAllIndicators(year,month);
    if(queryResult == null){
      queryResult = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    return queryResult;
  }
}
```

> Exception!!

```
2018-04-12 16:53:06.436 ERROR 13264 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testMapper' defined in file [/home/sossos/Projects/mockmvctest-ofspringboot-withmybatismapper/target/classes/com/wqk/mockmvctestofspringbootwithmybatismapper/mapper/TestMapper.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'sqlSessionFactory' or 'sqlSessionTemplate' are required
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1710) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:741) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:138) [spring-boot-test-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:107) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.postProcessFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:99) [spring-boot-test-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.injectFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:79) [spring-boot-test-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:54) [spring-boot-test-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:242) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68) [junit-rt.jar:na]
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47) [junit-rt.jar:na]
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242) [junit-rt.jar:na]
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70) [junit-rt.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'sqlSessionFactory' or 'sqlSessionTemplate' are required
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:193) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.mybatis.spring.support.SqlSessionDaoSupport.checkDaoConfig(SqlSessionDaoSupport.java:74) ~[mybatis-spring-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
at org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean.checkDaoConfig(MapperFactoryBean.java:73) ~[mybatis-spring-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
at org.springframework.dao.support.DaoSupport.afterPropertiesSet(DaoSupport.java:44) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
... 40 common frames omitted

2018-04-12 16:53:06.437 ERROR 13264 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@470f1802] to prepare test instance [com.wqk.mockmvctestofspringbootwithmybatismapper.controller.TestControllerTest@7159139f]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:107) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.postProcessFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:99) ~[spring-boot-test-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.injectFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:79) ~[spring-boot-test-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:54) ~[spring-boot-test-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:242) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68) [junit-rt.jar:na]
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47) [junit-rt.jar:na]
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242) [junit-rt.jar:na]
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70) [junit-rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testMapper' defined in file [/home/sossos/Projects/mockmvctest-ofspringboot-withmybatismapper/target/classes/com/wqk/mockmvctestofspringbootwithmybatismapper/mapper/TestMapper.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'sqlSessionFactory' or 'sqlSessionTemplate' are required
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1710) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:741) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:138) ~[spring-boot-test-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'sqlSessionFactory' or 'sqlSessionTemplate' are required
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:193) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.mybatis.spring.support.SqlSessionDaoSupport.checkDaoConfig(SqlSessionDaoSupport.java:74) ~[mybatis-spring-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
at org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean.checkDaoConfig(MapperFactoryBean.java:73) ~[mybatis-spring-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
at org.springframework.dao.support.DaoSupport.afterPropertiesSet(DaoSupport.java:44) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
... 40 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Welcome to StackoverFlow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn about [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You have the same problem as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43829482/webmvctest-in-spring-boot . Test for controller should not have `MybatisTest` or `AutoConfigureMybatis`. All dependencies of the controllers (services) should be mocked.

Comment: the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43829482/webmvctest-in-spring-boot isn't the same as me. and My problems is already solved. thank you very much. https://github.com/mybatis/spring-boot-starter/issues/227

Answer (score 1):

the question is already solved.
use @Import(TestServiceImpl.class) can operation the real db.
[the solved link address](https://github.com/mybatis/spring-boot-starter/issues/227)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this dependency into pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
   <artifactId>druid-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.9</version>
</dependency>
```