# Test slice with @WebMvcTest is loading a substantial amount of controllers unrelated with the target

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing

I have a spring boot application yielding numerous controllers and my goal is to create an integration test for a specific one. I read that we can achieve a test slice with the `@WebMvcTest` annotation that loads only what is necessary to deploy the target controller, **is this assumption correct**? Here is my test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(
        controllers = {DummyController.class},
)
public class DummyControllerIT {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

...
```

Unfortunately the execution attempts to deploy other controllers/services/repositories that have no relation to the target Controller, which forces me use `@MockBean` on each of them. I was under the impression that `@WebMvcTest` would spare me from having an extensive listing of declared controllers/services/repositories with the `@MockBean` annotation, **am I wrong?**

If I misinterpreted this and I am expected to use `@MockBean` on unrelated parts of the application, then **why is it better** to use `@WebMvcTest` instead of `@SpringBootTest`? On the other hand, **if I interpreted it correctly  what am I missing?**

---

Not sure if it is related but this is my initialiser:

```
@ComponentScan(scopedProxy = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableScheduling
@EnableCaching
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public TaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(Integer.parseInt(Objects.requireNonNull(env.getProperty("coreThreadPoolSize"))));
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(Objects.requireNonNull(env.getProperty("maxThreadPoolSize"))));
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5):

`@WebMvcTest` works by disabling full auto-configuration of your application and also filtering its component scanning so that only the parts that are needed are configured. Your main class, `Application`, is enabling auto-configuration (via `@SpringBootApplication`) but is also explicitly enabling component scanning as well as caching, security, JPA repositories, etc. `@WebMvcTest` doesn't switch off these explicitly enabled pieces so you're left having to mock things.

This problem and the recommended way to avoid it is [described in the reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-user-configuration). In short, you should move the various `@Enable…` annotations to separate `@Configuration` classes that are picked up by component scanning. You may also want to review the need for some of them. For example, `@EnableTransactionManagement` is covered by auto-configuration.

Your use of `@ComponentScan` is also problematic as it switches off the filtering that `@WebMvcTest` requires. Moving it away from the `@SpringBootApplication`-annotated class should fix this part of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Alternatively, would creating another similar to 'Application' but with your suggestions and assign it for this particular test work too? - Anyway, I will try to do this your way.

Comment: Yes, it would. Tests search for a class annotated with `@SpringBootConfiguration` (which `@SpringBootApplication` is annotated with). If they find one before reaching your main class, they'll use it.