# How to write a proper test case for controller, service and Dao in spirng boot using junit 5?

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit5

*How to write a proper test case for **controller**, **service** and **Dao** in **spring boot** using **junit 5** with clear explanation*

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot has a concept of test slices. This type of test configuration will setup only a part of your application and thus making tests:

- less likely to break on not-related change,
- faster in comparison to configuring all application services (using `@SpringBootTest` annotation).

For example `@JsonTest` slice will configure ObjectMapper (and some test utilities for JSON) in the same way as it would happen on production.

Anyway, to your mentioned types:

- *DAO* - use [`@DataJpaTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-jpa-test) slice - it will configure Hibernate with in-memory database and load all your entities and repositories.
- *Controllers* - use [`@WebMvcTest(YourController.class)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-mvc-tests) slice - it will load only configuration for Spring MVC, advices and your controller. You will be responsible to [deal with dependencies of that controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60192840/creating-integration-tests-in-a-monolithic-springboot-application/60194163#60194163).
- *Services* - pretty much depends on what is your service doing. I prefer using slices also for services depending on Spring-configured beans but your test can also be a very simple standard [j]unit test with all dependencies mocked away. - Depending on the compromise you want to make.

---

This does not change with the fifth version of junit. The only difference is that you no longer need to annotate your tests with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`.